# C# progressbar drawstring on form load

Tags: c#, progress-bar, default, drawstring, form-load

is there a way to write a default text on a progressbar in C# ?

this isn't working in Form_Load, but works fine on button click...

```
using (Graphics gr = progressBar1.CreateGraphics())
{
    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);
    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    gr.DrawString("hello world", 
                  new Font("Arial", 10.0f, FontStyle.Regular),
                  new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 
                  progressBar1.ClientRectangle, 
                  sf);                
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I would try putting a `Label` on top of the `ProgressBar` and update `Label.Text` together with `ProgressBar.Progress`. I've never done it myself, so I can't guarantee anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a one time Timer event to do this on as one option.

```
Timer t = new Timer();

Form_Load()
{
    t.Interval = 1000;
    t.Start();
}

static void t_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //One time event
    t.Stop();
    using (Graphics gr = progressBar1.CreateGraphics())
    {
        StringFormat sf = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap);
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        gr.DrawString("hello world", 
            new Font("Arial", 10.0f, FontStyle.Regular),
            new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 
            progressBar1.ClientRectangle, 
            sf);                
    }
}
```

One note on this:

As the `ProgressBar.Value` is changed; the `ProgressBar` graphics will change and overwrite the text you have drawn.  The comment by Nolonar to overlay the Progressbar with a `Label` and set it in front of the ProgressBar may be be more to your needs.

Otherwise, you'd have to handle the redrawing of the `ProgressBar` as the graphics change.

Comment: @ByteBlast 1 millisecond maybe better? :P

Comment: the label in front of the progressbar is ugly because i can't set the background to transparent (i need to change the color of the progressbar, depending on which directory i am, so no VisualStyles)